# Looking for a name of the theorem ${n \choose r} = \sum_{i=0}^{x} {x \choose i} {n-x \choose r-i}$

Tags: terminology, combinations

I just discovered a theorem by myself, but I'm sure it exists already, so I wanted to know what is it called?

$${n \choose r} = \sum_{i=0}^{x} {x \choose i} {n-x \choose r-i}$$ where $x\leq n-r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). Combinatorially, it expresses the fact that choosing $r$ objects out of $n$ can be done by splitting the $n$ objects into $x$ and $n-x$ objects and choosing any number $i$ of objects from the $x$ objects and then $r-i$ objects from the $n-x$ objects. (This shows that the restriction to $x\le n-r$ isn’t necessary.)

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you what is the difference between a theorem and an identity?

Comment: @HengWei: I don't think there's a clear-cut distinction. A theorem would tend to be something that requires a more elaborate proof than this does.

Answer (score 1):

Here [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) :

${\displaystyle {m+n \choose r}=\sum _{k=0}^{r}{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}}$

In your case, $m =x$, $n = n'-x$ and $i = k$

(I denoted your $n$ by $n'$)